Blended data not showing values
Can somebody tell me why Im not able to find a parameter value for an event in a dropdown filter when its a part of a blend (mixing twice the same property data) in looker studio, vs easily being able to find it when its a dropdown just of that source (without blend) ?The blend looks like this (screen)
looker studio data blend
Im trying to use the news_category_id value as a filter in my reports but its not showing certain values, whereas if I use the dimension being connected directly to the property data it works without any problems
